# Bit shifting of the 32-bit value with a subsequent expansion to the 64-bit type

Tags: c++

I have the following code that is giving an error of V629 from PVS Studio:

V629 Consider inspecting the 'length << 32' expression. Bit shifting of the 32-bit value with a subsequent expansion to the 64-bit type. circular_buffer.cc 84

```
bool CircularBuffer::AcquireCached(uint32_t key, size_t length,
                               Allocation* out_allocation) {
uint64_t full_key = key | (length << 32);
```

Comment: At the *very least* post the error message. Also please post a [mcve]. As it stands it is very unclear what you are asking and you provide little to no details that we would need to answer.

Comment: Can we have the full error message please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right answer was given earlier. This warning will be issued in case where the type size_t is 32-bit. If size_t is 64-bit, there won't be a mistake and the analyzer won't complain.

I would like to add couple of things. Firstly, I'd like to give a link to the docs: [V629](https://www.viva64.com/en/w/V629/). Secondly, I ask to use tag [pvs-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pvs-studio) on the issues relating to PVS-Studio analyzer.

Answer (score 3):

On a machine where `size_t` is 32 bit (so virtually on any modern 32 bit platform) wide this code doesn't do what you would think it does.

`length` is 32 bit wide, and there's no integral promotion, so the left shift by 32 bit invokes undefined behavior (it's UB to shift more than the type size). Even if it was well defined, it would shift all the bits out of the 32 bit value, so again, not what the author expected.

To make it work as intended, you have to cast to `uint64_t` *before* shifting, so that the shift is done with a 64-bit wide type and the bits can actually go somewhere useful.

```
uint64_t full_key = key | (uint64_t(length) << 32);
```

Notice that this happens to work fine on 64 bit platforms (where `size_t` is already 64 bit wide, so that shift is fine), so I imagine that's probably why this wasn't spotted earlier.

Comment: got you. It was driving me nuts to figure this one out.